# Customizing BASH output colors?

Tags: linux, bash, colors, bash-scripting

How do I customize bash colors for command output?

For example; I run `ls` and want directories and files to be a different color. How do I accomplish this? I see that distro's are doing this but I cannot find any documentation on colorizing `OUTPUT` from other commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally been able to get an answer to this question that does exactly what I expect it to.

For those interested the details; see the `man terminfo` and `man termcap` man pages. Those man pages layout terminal capabilities and environment variables that you can set allowing you to customize colors for any commands output.

One such example is having colored man pages:

```
man() {
    env LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\E[01;31m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\E[01;38;5;202m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\E[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\E[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\E[0;1;4;38;5;82m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\E[0m' \
    LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\E[04;38;5;51m' \
    man "$@"
}
```

The above variables will get applied to the environment of `man` when it's executed giving colors within a `man` page. These can also be applied to other commands (assuming it's using the `terminfo` output fields properly).

Answer (score 4):

That's not something your shell does. Color is generated through special control characters. Your terminal emulator needs to translate them into actual color.

For `ls`, you need to set

- `LSCOLORS` (FreeBSD, OS X, ..) or
- `LS_COLORS` (Linux).

See here for [an `LS_COLORS` generator](http://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/). You can then call

- `ls --color` (Linux)
- `ls -G` or set the `CLICOLOR` environment variable (BSD variants).

The rest is up to your terminal emulator. For example, my iTerm2 is configured like this:

[image]

Comment: You really can't. Most builtin commands won't colorize output unless explicitly called (like in `ls`). Most newer command-line tools have some sort of colorization, but it really depends. You can't find that out by just looking at the program. See uzsolt's answer below for a wrapper that would colorize anything.

Comment: Can you provide the exact LSCOLORS settings for the colors you've shown here?

Comment: @einpoklum Unfortunately not, sorry. I don't have this particular profile anymore, and you cannot directly convert iTerm2 colors to `LS_COLORS` as far as I know.

Comment: How about a reference to some similar, pastel-ish color scheme?

Comment: @josten Any specific reason for unaccepting this answer? Do you need any additional information?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check a wrapper, eg. [cw](http://cwrapper.sourceforge.net/):

> cw is a non-intrusive real-time ANSI color wrapper for common unix-based
>   commands on GNU/linux.  cw is designed to simulate the environment of the
>   commands being executed, so that if a person types 'du', 'df', 'ping', etc.
>   in their shell it will automatically color the output in real-time according
>   to a definition file containing the color format desired.  cw has support for
>   wildcard match coloring, tokenized coloring, headers/footers, case scenario
>   coloring, command line dependent definition coloring, and includes over 50
>   pre-made definition files.